# Ideas for a twist or plot point involving adopted character's parents

Tags: plot, subplot, twist

I'm writing a plot for a tabletop game, and one of my players is running a character who was taken from her home at a very young age. (it's her earliest memory) She was raised from that point on by an uncle she did not (and still does not) like who works for a mafia-like criminal organization. She joined up, too, once she was old enough. At the time of our plot, she's in her early 20s and hopes to gain a position of power in the organization. She knows nothing about her biological parents, but thinks they knew about (or at least suspected) her uncle's involvement in crime, and did not approve of his work. I'd like to bring her parents into the story at some point for a plot twist or side plot, but I'm drawing a complete blank as far as interesting ideas go. Please help!

**Additional info about the game:** The game takes place in the mid-90's and involves sometimes-friendly monsters. (Some are pets, some are killers) The criminal organization makes money by illegally catching and selling the monsters, and occasionally by plain old petty theft. Many people keep pet monsters for personal protection.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Josh*! Please note that "What should I write?" questions are off-topic here, as they will likely not be helpful for future readers and encourage opinion-based answers. Please [edit] your question to make it applicable to a wider future audience. For the moment I am voting to temporarily put this on hold as off-topic. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus Somehow I missed that in the help center. Believe it or not, I did actually check before posting. I think what I'm looking for is exactly this, from the help center: "We're looking to avoid questions where the intent is to generate ideas." So I don't think I can edit it in an acceptable way and still achieve the answers I'm looking for. Should I delete my question, or is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: There is no need to delete your question. When there are already answers it's considered rude to delete your question and thereby invalidate the work that others did for you. You can simply leave it as it is. As an unvoted, closed question with two answers, each of which have exactly one vote, this question will likely just silently sit in the depths of Writing.SE. Maybe it will help someone in the future, maybe not, but it doesn't look to me like it's doing any harm to anyone, so there is no need to delete it. You can simply ask a new question if you have one where we can help you.

Comment: If you want open-ended discussions the [chat] is normally the place to go, but the chat here on Writing.SE is basically dead most of the time. For example the [WorldBuilding chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) is more active (at least at American daytime). It's a different focus, but you would be more likely to get some ideas. WB has a Blog, too, where people sometimes post their own stories, so it's not too far-fetched to find at least someone willing to discuss plot ideas. (It's off-topic on the main site though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe she was taken as leverage because her parents were in debt to the criminal org. Maybe she discovers some paperwork revealing that. Even better if her current work for the org is somehow related to what caused her to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to give her some kind of medical condition that can only be cured by one or the other of her biological parents. In order to survive, she must receive blood, a transplant, or something else from either her mother or father.

This can be something that she seeks on her own, or, if she's already established herself as important to the organization, something that the leadership decides is necessary and arranges on her behalf.

If the leadership does it on her behalf, they could still keep her parentage a secret. (Simply telling her that they've found somebody compatible—or that they've identified a medical procedure that will help her.) It could be some inadvertent slip from a nurse or doctor at the hospital, a chance encounter with a parent, or something else that finally makes her aware of the relationship.